# Querying sub documents mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have below document structure in my sample app

[image]

The models are Student and Phone. I have configured it as like below

```
    var mongoose = compound.mongoose;

    var PhoneSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        type: String,
        number: String
    });

    var StudentSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        dept: String,
        year: String,
        phone: [PhoneSchema]    
    });

    var Phone = mongoose.model('Phone',PhoneSchema);
    var Student = mongoose.model('Student',StudentSchema);

    Phone.modelName = 'Phone';
    compound.models.Phone = Phone;

    Student.modelName = 'Student';
    compound.models.Student = Student;
```

I could able to insert a Student document and multiple phone documents within the student as shown.

I am trying to query the subdocument

```
compound.models.Student.findOne({ "name" : "prabhu" }, function(err, student){

    console.log(student);
    console.log("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

    ###########This line shows error, no method find one for student.phone.
    student.phone.findOne({ "number" : "123456" }, function(err, phone){
        console.log(phone);
    });

});
```

Please suggest the best method to do it.

Note : I am aware i can loop through the student.phone object, but i find its not efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

You need to pass on the selectors as well if you want to use findOne, 
so your function call will be like

```
compound.models.Student.findOne({ "name" : "prabhu" }, 'name dept', function(err, student)       {

//Do what you want;

});
```

EDITED:

```
  compound.models.Student.findOne({ "name" : "prabhu","phone.number":1234 }, 'name dept', function(err,     student)       {

//Do what you want;

});
```

Comment: actually i can get the query for Student working.. but i am looking for ability to query the sub documents as like i mentioned in the question.

Comment: Let me edit the answer to query the sub documents. Do let me know if that helped or you already had tried it before.

Comment: Yes, i tried it and it worked. But it would be great if i can able to query with the resultant student object as like we do in Rails.

Comment: I have not tried that though to query the returned object. You would have to loop through the student object to get your result. :( Will investigate more on that though.

Comment: Thanks for your interest..! I am also researching on this, will post if i find answer..